# Redirect to custom URL depending on referer URL in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to redirect to a custom URL after the confirmation in gravity forms, I set this in functions.php but I need to fix what is wrong with the code, I need to do it this way since I have 2 domains sharing the same form.

What I did was set a hidden field in the form with Default Value {referer}, and also allowed the field to be populated dynamically with parameter 'refurl':

```
add_filter('gform_confirmation', 'conditional_confirmation', 10, 4);

function conditional_confirmation($confirmation, $refurl, $entry, $ajax) {
    if ($refurl == 'http://www.example.com') {
        $confirmation = array('redirect' => 'http://www.google.com');
    }
  return $confirmation;


}
```

When clicking the confirmation button the form doesn't redirect anywhere. Do you guys know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Second parameter of the **add_filter** function should be the name of your callable function. Take a look at the WordPress documentation for add_filter hook function [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

If the name of second parameter is **conditional_confirmation** then you should call your function also **conditional_confirmation**.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that was the first step :). I fixed that but still not redirecting where it says..

Comment: You are also missing **return** in your callable function.

Comment: Yes, I had it correctly in the code, forgot to add it here, I just edited it. My doubt here is if I'm calling correctly the refurl / referer, if that is the correct way to populate the field into php. I also changed the priority to 100 to see if that worked, but it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, second argument for the filter is a $form object. So you need to get your hidden input value from the $form object.

Give an input name to that hidden field as 'refUrl' in the gravity field properties.

```
add_filter('gform_confirmation', 'conditional_confirmation', 10, 4);

function conditional_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax) {
    $input_name = 'refUrl';
    foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {
        if (isset($field['inputName']) && $field['inputName'] === $input_name) {
            $fieldName = 'input_' . $field['id'];
            $refurl = $_POST[$fieldName];
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($refurl == 'http://www.example.com') {
        $confirmation = array('redirect' => 'http://www.google.com');
    }
    return $confirmation;
}
```